# I can't cout string variables in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, window, dev-c++

Here is the code I am working on (I'm a beginner and it is practice code). It works fine, but I can't `cout` the title and director. Other than that, it works fine... I'm using dev cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct moviedata
{
    string title;
    string director;
    int year_released;
    double run_time;
};

void getinfo();
void showresult();

int main()
{
    getinfo();
    showresult();
    return 0;
}

void getinfo()
{
    moviedata m;

    cout << "What is title of movie?"<<endl;
    cin >> m.title;

    cout << "Who is the director of " << m.title << " ?"<<endl;
    cin >> m.director;

    cout << "What year was it released?"<<endl;
    cin >> m.year_released;

    cout << "What is the run time of " << m.title <<" ?"<<endl;
    cin >> m.run_time;
}

void showresult()
{
    moviedata m;

    cout << "You selected " << m.title << "directed by " << m.director ;

    cout << " which was released in " << m.year_released << " and is " << m.run_time <<" hours long"<<endl;
}
```

I need help. I can't `cout` string variables.

Comment: Since you're not initializing `m` in any way, the expected result would be no output.  Is that what you're getting?  You never specified the exact problem.

Comment: At a higher level: The `moviedata` object in `getinfo()` and the one in `showresult()` are two different objects, even though both are called `m`.  That's because of "scope".  (And then Mark's comment that the `m` in `showresult()` is default-initialized is correct).  You either need to have one object in a scope that both functions can see, or pass the objects between functions by using parameters and return values.

Comment: The `m` variables in your two functions are distinct variables. This is very basic things explained in any good c++ book.

Comment: FYI, the `m` variables will disappear after execution leaves the functions.  You may want to *pass* the `m` variable by reference or constant reference if you don't change the parameter.

Comment: Every `moviedata m;` declares & default initializes a separate object. You need a way of passing the data from one function to the other. You could e.g. change the signatures of the functions to return the object from `getinfo` and pass the data to `showresult` as function parameter by changing the signatures to `moviedata getinfo();` and `void showresult(moviedata const&);`. This requires an update of the function and `main` logic of course...

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line. And, note that `std::cout` and `std::cin` are tied together; when the code reads from `std::cin` it first flushes `std::cout`, so there's all the less reason for `std::endl` before reading.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you aen't able to print out strings.  The real problem is that the strings you are printing are simply blank to begin with.

When `main()` calls `getinfo()`, a new `moviedata` object is created, populated, and then destroyed.  When `main()` then calls `showresult()`, a new `moviedata` object is created, which is not populated, but is printed out.  The strings in that second object have been default-constructed and not had any values assigned to them.

What you need to do is *persist* a single `moviedata` object between `getinfo()` and `showresult()` so you don't lose your data, for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct moviedata
{
    string title;
    string director;
    int year_released;
    double run_time;
};

void getinfo(moviedata&);
void showresult(const moviedata&);

int main()
{
    moviedata m;
    getinfo(m);
    showresult(m);
    return 0;
}

void getinfo(moviedata &m)
{
    cout << "What is title of movie?" << endl;
    cin >> m.title;

    cout << "Who is the director of " << m.title << " ?" << endl;
    cin >> m.director;

    cout << "What year was it released?" << endl;
    cin >> m.year_released;

    cout << "What is the run time of " << m.title << " ?" << endl;
    cin >> m.run_time;
}

void showresult(const moviedata &m)
{
    cout << "You selected " << m.title << " directed by " << m.director;
    cout << " which was released in " << m.year_released << " and is " << m.run_time << " hours long" << endl;
}
```

You can then take that a step further by moving `getinfo()` and `showresult()` into `moviedata` itself, for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct moviedata
{
    string title;
    string director;
    int year_released;
    double run_time;

    void getinfo();
    void showresult() const;
};

int main()
{
    moviedata m;
    m.getinfo();
    m.showresult();
    return 0;
}

void moviedata::getinfo()
{
    cout << "What is title of movie?" << endl;
    cin >> title;

    cout << "Who is the director of " << title << " ?" << endl;
    cin >> director;

    cout << "What year was it released?" << endl;
    cin >> year_released;

    cout << "What is the run time of " << title << " ?" << endl;
    cin >> run_time;
}

void moviedata::showresult() const
{
    cout << "You selected " << title << " directed by " << director;
    cout << " which was released in " << year_released << " and is " << run_time << " hours long" << endl;
}
```